# My USB webcam is not being recognised

Tags: webcam

I have recently changed my computer software from Windows 8 to Ubuntu 14.04. I am aware of the app Cheese, and I know many people are struggling with the webcam not working with Cheese. For me, the webcam is not being recognised on any app or website. Could someone explain simply how to make my webcam work?

Comment: Can you please list the model of webcam you are using, and what kind of computer you have? Without information we are unable to answer the question or direct you to the correct duplicate question.

Comment: Could you post the output of `sudo lsusb -vvv` (open a terminal with **Ctrl+Alt+T** and type that command) ?

Comment: laptop= Toshiba satellite pro L300 
webcam= Logitech QuickCam E3560

Comment: I cannot do the sudo lsusb -vvv thing as I have a password set (by my mum) on my laptop (to stop me downloading viruses).

Comment: Sometimes the app luvcview works when cheese doesn't.  Try it.

Comment: Cheese is now working, but websites where the camera is needed don't work e.g. webcamtoy.com